# Running Linux kernel in Virtualbox

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtualbox, qemu

I just built a Linux kernel on Ubuntu and now I want to make it run on VirtualBox. I wanted it to be in an img format. I created a hard drive image by doing the commands:

```
$ qemu-img create disk.img 512M
$ mkfs.ext2 -F disk.img
```

What should I do next?

Comment: img format, you mean "raw" format right? Anyway Vbox supports it.

Comment: Your question looks vague now, were you trying to boot from the disk(that has a boot loader installed already), or use qemu to boot that disk with an external kernel file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you creating the disk manually?

You should use VirtualBox to create the disk while creating the VM, unless you plan to use it together with qemu. (why?)

Here, when adding disks, use the existing disk that you created.

[image]

Comment: All I have done is create the kernel. I want to take the bzImage and put that with a bootloader, and a hard drive image then run that in Virtualbox (or possibly qemu if there is a way to do both).

Comment: Could you give a step by step process?

Answer (score 3):

To run a kernel directly in `qemu` or `kvm`, use the `-kernel` argument:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-2-amd64
```

Virtualbox may have something similar.

If you really want it installed on a hard drive image, it's a bit harder.  You need a bootloader installed, which may also require a partition table.  Something like [SYSLINUX](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/SYSLINUX) or [EXTLINUX](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/EXTLINUX) could be straightforward, or you could just go straight ahead to what most real systems use and install [GRUB](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/).  For GRUB, the [instructions in Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter08/grub.html) will be helpful, as will the GRUB documentation itself.

Comment: I have tried to boot the kernel by doing the kernel argument. My issue was that I didnt have a hard drive image so it would not boot.

Comment: That's a very different problem.   You can add a hard drive with the `-hda` option.  Your kernel is booting, now you've moved into the realm of what the kernel itself is doing once it boots.

Comment: I know that I can add a hard drive by doing that command. My question is how do I create the image (preferably in img format)??

Comment: You already know how to create the image -- you listed the commands to do it. It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I want to create an img file that has grub, the linux kernel (bzImage) and I want to be able to run in virtualbox. Thats what I am asking

Comment: Did you use the two links I provided for how to set up GRUB?